# How do you limit the number of processes in Python to ensure it is memory safe with imported libraries?

Tags: python, memory-management, import, multiprocessing, memory-efficient

Warning! Don't try and run the example code, it could cause your whole computer to crash!

I have a class that is written to handle some complex calculation that involves several other modules:

```
# Some required libraries for calculation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

# Class to handle a single calculation
class B():

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    # Some long, complex calculation
    def Run(self):
        return self.arg**2
```

And I want to be able to run this calculation lots of times with different inputs using the multiprocessing module, and then process all the results together. I have another class to do this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from test import B

# Class to run lots of calculations and process results.
class A():

    def RunProcess(self, arg):
        b = B(arg)
        return b.Run()

    def Run(self, max_processes):
        pool = mp.Pool(max_processes)
        results = pool.imap(self.RunProcess, [i for i in range(10000)])
        # Do something with results.
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.Run(40)
```

My problem is that I'm doing this on a shared computer cluster and the importing of the other libraries for each process can use up a lot of memory, causing the computer to have a nasty crash if someone else is running calculations. Is there a better way to make this code memory safe than just limiting the number of processes?

Some notes:

Try/except blocks don't appear to work as intended, which I have read is to do with the underlying C implementation.

I've limited the imports to what I think is the bare minimum for the calculation

matplotlib is preventing me from using multithreading instead of multiprocessing